# CoreData NSFetchRequest returns results but section number of objects returns 0

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am currently trying to write my first CoreData project and am getting very confused. I am using the following code to setup a fetched results controller:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
        return _fetchedResultsController;

    Singleton *singleton = [Singleton sharedSingleton];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MapEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[singleton managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sName" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:8];

    // Finally check the results
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[singleton managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (MapEntity *map in fetchedObjects)
    {
        NSLog(@"Maps present in database: %@", map.sName);
    }


    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[singleton managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I put in the NSLog to see if the fetchRequest was finding results, and it does:

```
2013-01-28 11:20:14.735 WildMap_iOS[10931:16a03] Maps present in database: UK Capital Cities
2013-01-28 11:20:14.736 WildMap_iOS[10931:16a03] Maps present in database: The UK
2013-01-28 11:20:14.736 WildMap_iOS[10931:16a03] Maps present in database: Testing123
2013-01-28 11:20:14.736 WildMap_iOS[10931:16a03] Maps present in database: TestForPic
2013-01-28 11:20:14.736 WildMap_iOS[10931:16a03] Maps present in database: Scottish Map
2013-01-28 11:20:14.736 WildMap_iOS[10931:16a03] Maps present in database: Old Scotland
2013-01-28 11:20:14.736 WildMap_iOS[10931:16a03] Maps present in database: Old Scotland
2013-01-28 11:20:14.737 WildMap_iOS[10931:16a03] Maps present in database: Old Scotland
2013-01-28 11:20:14.737 WildMap_iOS[10931:16a03] Maps present in database: Field Concatination
```

However, when I try to use my fetchedResultsController to setup my tableView numberOfRowsInSection as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

The 'return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];' returns nil, even though the fetchRequest seems to be picking up the objects fine.

I was using this code fine, however I recently added an integer to the mapEntity (iID) and it made me delete the simulator data as the structure of the stored data had changed. After I removed the data and relaunched the application the code no longer works.

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? I don't think it's naming conventions as it worked before, and the fetchRequest is returning results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to what @Levi suggested, you should not access the instance variable `_fetchedResultsController` directly in `numberOfRowsInSection` (or in other table view data source methods). Always use the property accessor `self.fetchedResultsController`.

*Reason*: The `fetchedResultsController` getter method creates the fetched results controller if necessary. Accessing `_fetchedResultsController` directly might return `nil`.

**Update:** Another problem is the fetched results controller cache. From the documentation:

> Important: If you are using a cache, you must call
>   `deleteCacheWithName:` before changing any of the fetch request, its
>   predicate, or its sort descriptors. You must not reuse the same
>   fetched results controller for multiple queries unless you set the
>   `cacheName` to `nil`.
>   ...
>   Where possible, a controller uses a cache to avoid the need to repeat work performed in
>   setting up any sections and ordering the contents. The cache is maintained across launches of your application.

So you should either use `cacheName:nil` or ensure that the cache is deleted when any parameters of the FRC are changed.

Comment: Ah okay, I have changed my code to reflect this, however it still does not work. I have been checking all along whether _fetchedResultsController is valid, and it is. When I print out '[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:0]' I get '<_NSDefaultSectionInfo: 0xa10bb80>', however the sections parameter is still nil.

Comment: Can you NSLog() the contents of `[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects]` ?

Comment: You could also try `cacheName:nil` in the creation of the FRC, to avoid problems with wrong cache data.

Comment: Yes, and it lists all the MapEntitys with their relevant data. This is weird, it's finding the entries but it simply won't return a number in sections.

Comment: Yay thank you! It was the cacheName, is there any reason this isn't deleted and freed when the data is? Can you add this to your answer and I can accept.

Comment: @ElliottD'Alvarez: OK, I'm glad that your problem is solved. I have added the information to the answer. But credits should also go to Levi because he also made a valid point in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Before the `return _fetchedResultsController;` line in your method, tell the `NSFerchedResultsController` to execute the request:

```
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:NULL];
```

Comment: This still returns nil, does this mean something is wrong with the fetch?